# How to control Event permission?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, events, modern-team-site, homepage

I'm using SharePointOnline's Modern UI.

I added an event web part to the home page(Home.aspx).

I want to allow only administrators to add events.

However, if user have the add Item permission at the SharePoint access level, user can add events.

Is there any way to prevent adding events?
For general users, only reference is best.

I am very grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to give the Events list unique permissions and change the permissions so that the users no longer have permission to add items to the list. You can do this by going to Site Contents > Events > List settings (via the ribbon) > Permissions for this list

Comment: I'm really thankful to you. It was successful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such permission settings for **Events** web part.

As Callum Crowley said, it's necessary to change the permission on the source event list.

Grant other users except administrators in this list to read permission.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as I expected.